# Accessing user info from Firebase using model class Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm working on an app that uses an authorization system to log users in. Whenever a user registers, it updates just fine in my database:

```
User user = new User(username);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userid).child("profile").setValue(user);
```

The problem is, that when I try to access the data again in my next activity to try and get the current user's username, I get this error message:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type friendimals.Model.User
```

I'm using a basic model class:

```
public class User {

    private String username;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username) {
        this.username= username;

    }


    public String getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }
}
```

This is how I'm accessing the information in my database:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("profile").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //This is the line that is causing the crash
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                username_TextView.setText(user.getUsername());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Any ideas on what this error means and/or how to fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you checked?? `dataSnapshot!=null`

Comment: Yes I have checked to see what the value of dataSnapshot is. The value is "DataSnapshot { key = username, value = myUsername }"

Comment: Try like this `String userName= dataSnapshot.getValue();` let me know the response

Comment: Doing like you suggested gives an error since you cant set a String = to an object, but I did `String username = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();` and it worked!

Comment: okey i described the problem below in answer section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you don't have any key called `username` which you are specified in the model class. `dataSnapshot` only return the String value.

if your data structure is like this then only that work with model class

```
userid
|
username:usernameValue
```

Comment: So when I add more values to my model class, how should I go about accessing and/or setting each one of them?

Comment: suppose you have phone number then in the database it should be `phone:"phoneNumber"` under user id;
In model class you have a variable  called `String phone;` they are case_ sensitive

Comment: while setting the single values `ref.child("profile").child(user).child("phone").setValue(phoneNUmber);`
or use `HashMap` for setting multiple Values